# command to print a page in php without prompt

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I am using following code in php, html and javascript to print a html page and redirect to another page. It displays a prompt. I need that page to be printed without showing printing prompt/screen and automatically redirect to new php page.

```
     <input type="button" value="Print & Do New Transaction" class="button" id="payout_print"  onclick="window.print();window.location.href='transaction/admin/new_transaction'">
```

I have gogled it, but didn't get any useful answer that I am looking for. How to do this?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is not possible. I would be worried if websites I visit could print a page on my printer without my knowledge...?

Comment: There is a print button. After clicking that button, the page will be printed. But i need it without prompt or any printing dialogue box.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It would still be a massive security issue if you could do this. The print dialogs are there for a reason. How do I know that when I press your button on your website you won't tell my printer to print hundreds of random pages?

Comment: I will handle security issues. That's not a big deal. But, how to print page without prompt?

Comment: There are hacks floating around for IE by the looks of it BUT it simply isn't possible. It would be nightmare if it was. Perhaps you can open a new window that contains the print dialog and then redirect the user on the current window?

Answer (score -2):

For redirect a page you need to do:

```
<?
header("Location: destination_page.php");
exit;
?>
```

Remember to don't print any html code before this code because you'll get an error

Comment: redirection is done, that is not my problem. I need the redirection without showing printing prompt(screen). How to do that?